# python group float value

Tags: python, list

i have x and y value for point in range 0 to 1 and i want to group them with values that are closer to each other but first these should be grouped on basis of y values then on i want to create sub groups in each group on basis of x values

my values are like

```
y=[0.20854389667510986, 0.21354246139526367, 0.2514365017414093, 0.2824919819831848, 
     0.28884729743003845, 0.2938481867313385, 0.29938602447509766, 0.3079403340816498, 
     0.3110620379447937]
x=[0.19389697909355164, 0.34383803606033325, 0.42771604657173157, 0.5027003884315491, 
     0.27740684151649475, 0.5065063238143921, 0.5693719983100891, 0.6398013830184937, 
     0.7191168665885925]
```

any help

**EDITED**

bellow are example of images green are digits i need and red are non desired digits
[image]

[image]

below is my code that i am currently using

```
objs = [{'box': (0.42659902572631836, 0.7797865271568298, 0.8791541457176208, 0.8509170413017273), 'class_name': '4',
     'score': 0.99999213},
    {'box': (0.38698509335517883, 0.47336792945861816, 0.8555437922477722, 0.5579431056976318), 'class_name': '4',
     'score': 0.9999858},
    {'box': (0.41911759972572327, 0.6990442872047424, 0.8730689287185669, 0.775518000125885), 'class_name': '2',
     'score': 0.9999598},
    {'box': (0.42790335416793823, 0.8458782434463501, 0.8958504796028137, 0.9237207174301147), 'class_name': '8',
     'score': 0.99989796},
    {'box': (0.3866911232471466, 0.6215671896934509, 0.8674313426017761, 0.6978859305381775), 'class_name': '6',
     'score': 0.9997212},
    {'box': (0.4925450384616852, 0.27575790882110596, 0.8116368651390076, 0.32022011280059814), 'class_name': '1',
     'score': 0.9975745},
    {'box': (0.37777039408683777, 0.551058292388916, 0.8532172441482544, 0.6227307319641113), 'class_name': '5',
     'score': 0.99741983},
    {'box': (0.40477627515792847, 0.9192683696746826, 0.8955397009849548, 0.9945260286331177), 'class_name': '5',
     'score': 0.9972119},
    {'box': (0.4721110463142395, 0.22912952303886414, 0.8121180534362793, 0.3223329484462738), 'class_name': '4',
     'score': 0.8815911}]
sorted_objs = sorted(objs, key=lambda obj: obj['box'][0])
groups = [[]]
active = 0
min_distance = 0.03
i = 0
groups[active].append(sorted_objs[i])
i+=1
while i < len(sorted_objs):
   if abs(sorted_objs[i-1]['box'][0] - sorted_objs[i]['box'][0]) <=min_distance:
       groups[active].append(sorted_objs[i])
   else:
       groups.append([])
       active += 1
       groups[active].append(sorted_objs[i])
   i += 1
print([box['class_name'] for box in sorted(sorted(groups,key=lambda key:len(key))[-1], key=lambda key: key['box'][1])])
```

in above code i am using fixed min_distance but i want it to be more dynamic

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add the expected output

Comment: can you share your final result which you require and effort you have done to solve this problem

Comment: The idea of grouping is slighty unclear, please provide expected result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. Could you add an example output?

Comment: I don't understand it well, you want to concatenate them and sort it?

Comment: @ipj i am actually trying to read number from image and i am get  getting min(x,y) and max(x,y) for all numbers but there are some numbers that i don't need but but there location is not fixed but one thing is clear that numbers i am interested are are in form of group and min group length is 3 and other numbers can be 2 or 1 so i want to group all numbers according to their y values and then i will drop all groups that have length lower then 3 and then i will group on basis of x axis

Comment: Maybe attaching result will help to understand whole idea. Can You share please what is the correct result based on `x` and `y` arrays of numbers? Then we may think how to code it in Python.

Comment: @ipj i had updated my question with images and with currently code i am using

Comment: OK, so You have a list of coordinates of rectangle areas which refer to as I suppose image of LCD of some kind of digital electricity meter. How do You exactly formulate the problem?

Comment: @ipj what do you mean by formulating problem?

Comment: You've posted input data and code, but what result is desired in terms of logic of all this transformations, what is the purpose? Is there any specific problem with Your code, why variable `min_distance` needs to be 'more dynamic'? I assume question is specific to image recognition or classification but to receive reasonable response elaborate more please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217059/discussion-between-kei-nagae-and-ipj).